# If I have a random vector $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i =1$, why does the joint density function not exist?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If I have a random vector $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i =1$, I am wondering why the joint density, $f_{X_1, \ldots, X_n}(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is degenerate, is there a specific reason why? thanks.

Comment: Let us denote $\ell = \{(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \in \Bbb{R}^n : x_1 + \cdots + x_n = 1 \}$. If $X$ have joint density, then $$1 = \Bbb{P}(X \in \ell) = \int_{\ell} f_X(\mathrm{x}) \, d\mathrm{x} = 0$$ because $\ell$ has zero Lebesgue-measure, a contradiction!$

Comment: @SangchulLee Can I ask why $\ell$ has zero Lebesgue-measure? And why does $1 = \Bbb{P}(X \in \ell)$? thank you!

Comment: As an intuitive thought, you could expect your joint density to have $n$ dimensions, but your constraint reduces it to $n-1$ dimensions. Now consider a point on a line, or a line on a plane, or a plane in a volume: it takes up a zero fraction of the total

Comment: $X \in \ell$ is just a paraphrasing of the condition $X_1 + \cdots + X_n = 1$. So $\Bbb{P}(X \in \ell)$ simply means that $X_1 + \cdots + X_n = 1$ with probability 1. Also, since $\ell$ is a $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane in $\Bbb{R}^n$, it must have zero ($n$-dimensional) volume.

Comment: Trivial example in 2-D: Let $X_1 \sim Unif(0,1)$ and $X_2 = 1 - X_1 \sim Unif(0,1).$ Obviously, $X_1 + X_2 = 1,$ but $f(x_1, x_2) = 1$ on the unit square cannot be their joint PDF.

Comment: @BruceET Can I ask why you took $f(x_1, x_2) =1$?

Comment: Just as the simplest impossibility, I guess. All probability is on a diagonal _line_ of the square.

Comment: @BruceET This is a bad question but why can't we take $f(x_1,x_2) = 1$? Is it because it doesn't integrate to $1$ on the diagonal?

Comment: Because joint PDF $f(x_1, x_2) = 1$ on the unit square places _0 probability_ on the diagonal.

Comment: I see, so basically here the double integral on the pdf will always be zero since I can only integrate from the same point to the same point and so I can never find a height large enough to accommodate even if I took $f(x_1, x_2) = c$ for any $c$ large?